# How to apply a limit just for joining table in MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table named category and content (each category can have many contents), and this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM categories ca 
LEFT JOIN content co ON co.cat_id=ca.id
```

I want to apply limit on it that query fetch 10 content for each category.

How should I query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not [`rank`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#RANK.28.29_window_function) function on MySQL.

You should use variables. I wrote [this snipped](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9000/10/0) for you. Transpose it to your own schema:

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
--c are categories
create table c ( id int, n varchar(100) );

--p are contents
create table p ( id int, fk_c int, n varchar(100) );

insert into c values
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B');

insert into p values
(1,1,'a'),
(2,1,'b'),
(3,1,'d'),                          <-- id=3, over the limit set to 2
(4,2,'e');
```

**Query**:

```
select * from (
  SELECT p.*, 
         @n := ( case when @c <> c.id then 1 else @n+1 end) as "num",
         @c := c.id as "prev c"
    FROM c left outer join p on c.id = p.fk_c, 
    (SELECT @n := 0, @c = 0)  r
) p  
    where p.num <= 2                <-- limiting to 2.
```

**Results**:

```
| id | fk_c | n | num | prev c |
|----|------|---|-----|--------|
|  1 |    1 | a |   1 |      1 |
|  2 |    1 | b |   2 |      1 |
                                     <-- id=3 missing ;)
|  4 |    2 | e |   1 |      2 |
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it work fine in sqlfiddle but in my phpmyadmin query just return 2 rows - but say  Showing rows 0 - 2 (3 total, Query took 0.0020 seconds.) - any idea?

Comment: Data should be ordered by category and content. Try to include `order by` clause.

Comment: @mmjj, order matters, insert `order by` to nested query: `... @n := 0, @c = 0)  r
    order by c.id, p.id
) p ...`. This solve your issue?

Comment: problem in first comment fixed by adding colon to @c = 0 => @c := 0 (is it true or I broke the code?)..... but now if table p has row of fk_c=1 after fk_c=2 show it(I think this is what you mentioned for ordering is matter but order by not work(it just order final result))

Comment: by changing this row of query `FROM c left outer join p on c.id = p.fk_c,`  to `FROM  c left outer join (select * from p order by p.fk_c) p on c.id = p.fk_c,` now it work fine :).. one more question: is this single query more efficient than doing multiple mysql and php job?